# python3 import into csv displaying in every cell

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I'm new to python and I'm trying to import some URL's i scraped into a csv file but it is parsing every character in the web addresses into a difference cell.  Here's my code:

```
    import csv
    with open('test.csv', 'w') as f:
     csv_writer = csv.writer(f)
     csv_writer.writerow(['Web Address'])
     csv_write.writerows(filter_records)
```

If i put brackets around the filter_records variable, it just returns the entire list of URLs in a single cell

Any guidance would be great.

Thanks
Garrett

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
import csv

filter_records = ['www.google.com', 'www.stackoverflow.com', 'www.facebook.com']

with open('test.csv', 'w') as f:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(f)
    csv_writer.writerow(['Web Address'])
    [csv_writer.writerow([record]) for record in filter_records]
```

or

```
import csv

filter_records = ['www.google.com', 'www.stackoverflow.com', 'www.facebook.com']

with open('test.csv', 'w') as f:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(f)
    csv_writer.writerow(['Web Address'])
    csv_writer.writerows([record] for record in filter_records)
```

This happens because python a string is a list of chars. `writerow()` method receives a list as param, and `writerows()` receives a list of lists. So, you will get an comma-split string in every row.